# need help on xslt transformations regarding the namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, tridion

I am working on XSLT transformations. I am stuck at one point.

Source XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <Content xmlns="uuid:4522eb85-0a47-45f9-8e2b-1f82c78fa920">
    <first xmlns="uuid:4522eb85-0a47-45f9-8e2b-1f82c78fa920">Hello World.This is Fisrt       field</first>
    <second xmlns="uuid:4522eb85-0a47-45f9-8e2b-1f82c78fa920">Hello World.This is second      field2</second>
   </Content>
```

Output Format required:

```
<aaa>Hello World.This is Fisrt   field</aaa>
<bbb>Hello World.This is second field</bbb>
```

Please suggest a solution for this.

I have tried this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="uuid:4522eb85-0a47-45f9-8e2b-1f82c78fa920">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <aaa>
    <xsl:value-of select="Content/first"/>
    </aaa>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output that i got is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <aaa xmlns="uuid:4522eb85-0a47-45f9-8e2b-1f82c78fa920"></aaa>
```

Output required is

```
<aaa>Hello World.This is Fisrt   field</aaa>
```

Comment: what have you got so far and what is the issue?

Comment: i tried this but there was no out put. 
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="uuid:4522eb85-0a47-45f9-8e2b-1f82c78fa920">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <aaa>
    <xsl:value-of select="Content/first"/>
    </aaa>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet> 

output is
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <aaa xmlns="uuid:4522eb85-0a47-45f9-8e2b-1f82c78fa920"></aaa>

Comment: Tried what? - I see no XSLT script

Comment: That should be in the question not a comment

Comment: I have addred the script taht i have tried.Please help.

Comment: I have used the formatter again - but please look at the page after you have written or edited and see if you can read it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one that does what you want, sort of, see comments below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:x="uuid:4522eb85-0a47-45f9-8e2b-1f82c78fa920">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="root">
      <xsl:element name="aaa">
        <xsl:value-of select="x:Content/x:first"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="bbb">
        <xsl:value-of select="x:Content/x:second"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

While certain xslt processors allow you to have more than one root element in the result, this isn't advisable as it contradicts syntactically with the standard.

Comment: "contradicts syntactically with the standard" means it is not XML and XML tools must reject it

Comment: Or you might wish to specify a different output format. If you say <xsl:output method="text"/> you won't have this constraint.